# What happened with reputation charts?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, reputation-graph, reputation-leagues

Reputations charts viewed by [Month](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow) and [Week](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow) on SO somehow "disintegrate". But Quarter, Year, and All Time reputation-views look correct.

EDIT:

I checked that again, but no changes in compare with yesterday status

Comment: Well, the numbers look to be all kinds of *wrong*, but can you be more specific as to what you mean by "disintegrate"?

Comment: -1,716 for me - DOH!!

Comment: @Shog9 I can't be more specific, because simple not is possible increase reputations in 2-8k per three days for bunch of users,

Comment: @mKorbel: yeah, I see the bogus numbers - if that's what you're talking about, that's all I need to know.

Comment: @Shog9 agreed that's right, thanks

Comment: @Shog9 looks like as value are correct, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not really clear what you mean by "disintegrate" - but certainly they don't tie up with what happens if you look at the "reputation by time" part of the user accounts.

I have a sneaking suspicion this *may* be due to questions being undeleted: so when compared with a snapshot of reputation taken (say) on Sunday at midnight, [Michael Stum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91/michael-stum?tab=reputation&sort=post) may indeed have over 8K more reputation than he did before... but most of that reputation was actually *earned* before Sunday... it's just that it popped back into existence after being deleted.

Alternatively, it's just a nasty bug somewhere which has no particular way of squinting at it to make sense ;)

Comment: too hard to say whatever wise, without looking into the Database, nobody knows ....

Answer (score 3):

[Emmett fixed this.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124953/does-it-make-sense-that-migrated-questions-doubles-your-network-reputation/124956#comment337022_124953)

[This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl) still sticks out like a sore thumb in the month league, but that appears to be completely legit. He really has answered 290 questions in under 2 weeks.

Comment: You used the same link twice.

Comment: Fixed... That's what I get for rushing